# Is it possible to use Django 1.2 on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I want to use the `in` operator in my Google App Engine project which was introduced in [`Django 1.2`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator):

```
{% if "bc" in "abcdef" %}
  This appears since "bc" is a substring of "abcdef"
{% endif %}
```

I [found out](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) that is possible to use version 1.0 or 1.1on GAE, but nothing for 1.2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bundle any version of Django with your application and deploy it.

Django 1.2.4 will almost certainly be included in the next release of App Engine; it's in the [pre-release SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/list) 1.4.2 that was put out late last week.  Assuming nothing goes horribly wrong, the prerelease features usually make it to the production site in a week or two.

Comment: But is it possible to deploy this version?

Comment: You an download the 1.2.4 release and bundle it with your app, or simply wait for it to go live.

Comment: Django 1.2.5 made it into the [App Engine 1.4.2 release](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/02/app-engine-142-sdk-api-updates-and.html)!  Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

It appears so, I found this - http://www.deck.cc/django_1.2_on_google_app_engine.html

Comment: Ah ok then. Although, I believe this did answer your original question :)

Comment: maybe this did answer my question.. but I didn't manage to make it work straight away.. Probably it will work if I spend some time.. but since the project already started I wanted something easier.. this is not what I was looking for.. I found this by myself as well.. btw.. have you tried it? have you made it work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can use that version, but you should certainly be able to use SmileyChris's [smart_if snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/) which was the basis of the extended if functionality in Django 1.2.